# Angularjs Filter to pass data from one table to another table (using a checkbox)

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to populate a table with data being provided by another table.
Table One has all of the data with a Checkbox for each item.
Table Two should contain only those items that have been checked in Table One.

I can see that the 'Checked' value gets Set to true, but does not work (I get all data, all the time in Table Two).
$scope.data
Object {key: "3", value: "c", $$hashKey: "006", checked: true}

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gedave/A6bt3/%20JSFiddle)

Desired Result:

[image: Desired Result]

```
<span>Table One</span>
<div ng-controller="checkBoxCtrl">
<table width="400" border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="data in tableOne" id="item{{data.key}}">
        <td width="20px">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.checked">
        </td>
        <td>{{data.key}}</td>
        <td>{{data.value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br>
<span>Table Two</span>
<table width="400" border="1">
        <tr ng-repeat="data in tableOne | filter: data.checked==true">
            <td>{{data.key}}</td>
            <td>{{data.value}}</td>
        </tr>

</table>


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function checkBoxCtrl($scope){
        $scope.tableOne=[
                        {key: '1',  value: 'a'},
                        {key: '2',  value: 'b'},
                        {key: '3',  value: 'c'},
                        {key: '4',  value: 'd'}
                        ];  
        };
```

Comment: What happens if your filter is filter:  data.checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the syntax to filter a property....basically it's an object but I guess in angular  terms it might be considered an expression. I'm not 100% sure how to define it in words...but it works

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in tableOne | filter: {checked:true}">
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/charlietfl/A6bt3/2/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

simply remove one of the equal signs.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in tableOne | filter: checked=true">
```

Comment: Thanks, I was 'So Close'.